# Unable to paste links to our site into Facebook? Incorrect errors on Facebook scraper / debug tool?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Have Facebook changed something over the last two weeks?
When we post links to our website into Facebook it no longer displays images or descriptions!  :(

After going mad trying to track down what this was, we eventually found ourselves using the Facebook debugger tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and have been trying the following URL:

https://www.ledwarehouseuk.com/LED-Lights-Bulbs.php?lbid=371

When we initially click debug, we are told that...

"The 'og:type' property is required, but not present." ...even though this definitely IS present in the source code.

However, if we click the "Fetch new scrape information" button for the same URL we are presented with the following two errors:

Object at URL 'https://www.ledwarehouseuk.com/LED-Lights-Bulbs.php?lbid=371' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

Warning
Curl Error : SSL_CONNECT_ERROR error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Again, og:title exists in our code.  I have no idea what the CURL error is.
Can anyone help?  This has totally ruined the business side of our Facebook operations and I can't find any definitive answer as to why this is happening despite spending days trawling forums etc.

I would really appreciate your help.  Thank you.
NJ

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Delete the parameter -SSLv3 in SSL Cipher Suite in Apache Configuration. Restart Apache.

Comment: I basically resubmitted with non-https URL's and that did the trick.  The problem was related to SSLv3 but that was already switched off to protect against the POODLE vulnerability. Thank you Paulo.

Comment: Re-enabling `SSLv3` may leave your visitors open to the POODLE attack, it's usually disabled as the protocol has significant vulnerabilities and is deprecated. Double check your SSL settings using something like the SSL Labs test (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).